# Loop for creating key based on the name of other key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

Following is a snapshot of the data which I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'X1': [7,7,7,7,9],
    'X2': [8,9,7,5,6],
})
print(df)
```

I am looking for a loop that will Identify how many "X" keys I have and then, based on these "X" keys, it will create 'Y' keys. In the above case, I have X1 and X2, therefore, the new keys are Y1 and Y2(please see the code below).

If I had X1, X2, and X3 keys, then, the loop would automatically create Y1= 1, Y2= 2, and Y3= 3 keys and so on.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'X1': [7,7,7,7,9],
    'X2': [8,9,7,5,6],
    'Y1': [1,1,1,1,1],
    'Y2': [2,2,2,2,2],
})
print(df2)
```

How can I get these desired results?

Comment: Which values are you going to put to those new columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you need to create new columns with values based on the previous column suffix

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'X1': [7,7,7,7,9],
    'X2': [8,9,7,5,6],
    'X3': [18,19,17,15,16]
})

for col in df.columns:
    if col.startswith('X'):
        df['Y'+col[1:]] = int(col[1:])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     brand  X1  X2  X3 Y1 Y2 Y3
0  Yum Yum   7   8  18  1  2  3
1  Yum Yum   7   9  19  1  2  3
2  Indomie   7   7  17  1  2  3
3  Indomie   7   5  15  1  2  3
4  Indomie   9   6  16  1  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked Perfectly. Also, I got to know about startwith command.

Comment: that's great! I'm also learning and discovering new things everyday :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```py
current_columns = df.columns

for c in current_columns:
    if c[0] == 'X':
        df['y'+c[1:]] = int(c[:1])

print(df.head())
```

Comment: In the new column, I need the numbered part of the X variable. For example, if variable is X1 then in Y1 all the values would be 1, if variable is X2 then all the values in Y2 would be 2.

Comment: @Ahmed -- you can use `int(c[1])` for the number part of the X variable assuming you want it converted to an int, otherwise, you will get '1', '2',  for 'X1', 'X2' without the conversion.

Comment: @DarrylG The problem with ```int(c[1])``` is that it only works till X9. For example, if is X9, then the value of Y is 9, however, if X10, then the value of Y becomes 1 instead of 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: In case anyone would be wondering in future, to get the answer to the problem I proposed, we need to replace ```int(c[1])``` with ```int(c[1:])```.

Comment: @Ahmed -- yes, good catch.

Comment: Got it. I didn't understand which value should be used. I fixed it